# C macro preprocessor mapping a numer to a type

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to map a number to a keyword type in C. Is there anyway to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memory.h"

#define DOUBLE_TYPE 1
#define INT_TYPE 2

#define OBJECT_TYPE(Y)
        #if Y == DOUBLE_TYPE \
                double \
        #elif Y == INT_TYPE \
                int \
        #else \
                int \
        #endif \

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        unsigned int type = 1;
        OBJECT_TYPE(type) value = 0.5f;
        printf("%f\n", value);

        return 0;
}
test.c:11:3: error: missing binary operator before token "double"
   double \
```

I want to be able to cast a `void*` to a specific type known by the integer code.

Comment: The C **pre**processor has no concept of data types. You cannot nest directives. And C is statically typed. What you try does not make any sense. It is an XY problem. What do you want to solve?

Comment: The preprocessor is a compile-time thing, that runs in a separate phase before the actual compilation takes place. The preprocessor uses it's own separate language, and have no concept of C variables.

Comment: Furthermore, there's no such thing as a `default` type.

Comment: So the only way to do it parse my own files? I am trying to create my own object type system in C.  If I have an unknown void* and I know the data type by integer code then I want to be able to cast the void*.

Comment: It's not really clear what "it" is - what's a more realistic example of the problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible with macros.  They only do compile time text substitution, while what you want depends on runtime values.

If you want to effectively have a variable with a variant type, use a `union`:

```
struct var_type {
    int type;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
    } value;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct var_type value = { DOUBLE_TYPE, { d = 0.5f }};

    switch (value.type) {
    case DOUBLE_TYPE:
        printf("%f\n", value.value.d);
        break;
    case INT_TYPE:
        printf("%d\n", value.value.i);
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d\n", value.value.i);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to cast a void* to a specific type known by the integer code.

Comment: You can't do that @eat_a_lemon

Comment: @eat_a_lemon Then check the type and cast it to that type.

Comment: @dbush yea I guess the union replaces void* with a list of known types.